# Caesar Encryption in C

Tags: c, encryption, caesar-cipher, block-cipher

Hello I am working on a Caesar encryption program. Right now it takes as an input the file with the message to encrypt, the key

The input is currently in this format:

"text.txt", "ccc"

I need to convert this into taking a number so that it fits my requirements, so something like this:

"text.txt", "3"

Then i need to convert this "3" back into "ccc" so that the program still works. The logic being that 3 translates to the third letter of the alphabet "c", and is repeated 3 times. Another example would be if the key entered is "2", it should return "bb".

This is what i have so far but its giving me a lot of warnings and the function does not work correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void number_to_alphabet_string(int n) {
    char buffer[n];
    char *str;
    str = malloc(256);

    char arr[8];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        buffer[i] = n + 64;
        //check ASCII table the difference is fixed to 64
        arr[i] = buffer[i];
        strcat(str, arr);
    }

    printf(str);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *pt_path = argv[1];  //text.txt
    char *key = argv[2];    //3
    number_to_alphabet_string((int)key); //should change '3' to 'CCC'
}
```

Comment: "not working" is never a good problem description. Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result. More importantly, now would be a good time to learn to debug your own code. Run your code in a debugger and trace its flow and variable values as it runs. [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Ive tried for a few hours to run a debugger, but i cant figure out how in C. Watched a few videos and installed everything but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a function

```
void number_to_alphabet_string(int n)
```

that  takes an int but you call it with a char*

```
char* key = argv[2];    //3
number_to_alphabet_string(key);
```

My compiler says

> 1>C:\work\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp(47,34): warning C4047: 'function': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'

You need

```
char* key = argv[2];    //3
number_to_alphabet_string(atoi(key));
```

to convert that string to a number

Comment: Oh yes you are correct, i was trying it with type casting to an int but that works too. Still get a bunch of warning though and an incorrect ouput

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use a cast to cast from a char array to an int, you have to use functions, such as `atoi()`.
2. You never free your str after you allocate it. You should use `free(str)` when you no longer need it. Otherwise, it will cause a memory leak, which means the memory that you malloc() will always be occupied until your process dies. C doesn't have garbage collection, so you have to do it yourself.
3. Don't write things such as `char buffer[n];`, it can pass the compile of GCC, but it can't in MSVC.
   And that isn't the stander way of declaring an array with variable length. use

```c
char* buffer = malloc(n);

//don't forget to free() in order to avoid a memory leak
free(buffer);
```

Comment: In C, it is advisable to not cast the return of `malloc`. See: [*Do I cast the result of malloc?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2505965)

Answer (score 0):

With `char *key = argv[2];`, the cast `(int) key` does not reinterpret the *contents* of that string as a valid integer. What that cast does is take the *pointer value* of `key`, and interprets *that* as an integer. The result of this is implementation-defined, or [undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) if the result cannot be represented in the integer type (a likely outcome if `sizeof (int) < sizeof (char *)`).

The C standard does not define any meaning for these values.

Here is a test program that, depending on your platform, should give you an idea of what is happening (or failing to happen)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (sizeof (long long) >= sizeof (char *))
        printf("Address %p as an integer: %lld (%llx)\n",
                (void *) argv[0],
                (long long) argv[0],
                (long long) argv[0]);
}
```

As an example of implementation-defined behaviour, on my system this prints something like

```
Address 0x7ffee6ffdb70 as an integer: 140732773948272 (7ffee6ffdb70)
```

On my system, casting that same pointer value to `(int)` results in [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

*Note that `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are the proper types for treating a pointer value as an integer, but these types are optional.*

---

To actually convert a string to an integer, you can use functions such as `atoi`, `strtol`, or `sscanf`. Each of these have their pros and cons, and different ways of handling / reporting bad input.

Examples without error handling:

```
int three = atoi("3");
long four = strtol("4", NULL, 10);
long long five;
sscanf("5", "%lld", &five);
```

---

`number_to_alphabet_string` has a few problems.

`malloc` can *fail*, returning `NULL`. You should be prepared to handle this event.

In the event `malloc` succeeds, the contents of its memory are *indeterminate*. This means that you need to initialize (at least partially) the memory before passing it to a function like `strcat`, which expects a proper null terminated string. As is, `strcat(str, arr);` will result in [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Additionally, memory allocated by `malloc` should be deallocated with `free` when you are done using it, otherwise you will create [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

```
char *foo = malloc(32);

if (foo) {
    foo[0] = '\0';
    strcat(foo, "bar");
    puts(foo);
    free(foo);
}
```

In general, `strcat` and the additional buffers are unnecessary. The use of `char arr[8];` in particular is unsafe, as `arr[i] = buffer[i];` can easily access the array out-of-bounds if `n` is large enough.

Additionally, in `strcat(str, arr);`, `arr` is also never null terminated (more [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior)).

Note also that `printf(str);` is generally unsafe. If `str` contains format specifiers, you will again invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) when the matching arguments are not provided. Use `printf("%s", str)`, or perhaps `puts(str)`.

---

As far as I can tell, you simply want to translate your integer value `n` into the uppercase character it would be associated with if *A=1, B=2, ...* and repeat it `n` times.

To start, there is no need for buffers of any kind.

```
void number_to_alphabet_string(int n) {
    if (1 > n || n > 26)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            putchar('A' + n - 1);

    putchar('\n');
}
```

When passed `5`, this will print `EEEEE`.

If you want to create a string, ensure there is an additional byte for the terminating character, and that it is set. `calloc` can be used to *zero out* the buffer during allocation, effectively null terminating it.

```
void number_to_alphabet_string(int n) {
    if (1 > n || n > 26)
        return;

    char *str = calloc(n + 1, 1);

    if (str) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            str[i] = 'A' + n - 1;

        puts(str);
        free(str);
    }
}
```

*Note that dynamic memory is not actually needed. `char str[27] = { 0 };` would suffice as a buffer for the duration of the function.*

A cursory `main` for either of these:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void number_to_alphabet_string(int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1)
        number_to_alphabet_string(atoi(argv[1]));
}
```

*Note that with an invalid string, `atoi` simply returns `0`, which is indistinguishable from a valid `"0"` - a sometimes unfavourable behaviour.*